# VBA excel ByRef argument type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

VBA in Excel - I am trying to send a custom data type to a sub like this:

```
Public Type emailBody
  emailAddress As String
End Type

Sub SendEmail(email As emailBody)
   Dim queryString as String
   queryString = "email=" & email.emailAddress
   'email sending code goes here
End Sub
```

And in my form action:

```
Private Type emailBody
  emailAddress As String
End Type

Private Sub sendemail_Click()
   Dim emailFields as emailBody
   Dim emailAddress As String
   emailFields.emailAddress = "myemail@example.com"  
   Call SendEmail(emailFields) 
End Sub
```

I am getting this error:

```
ByRef argument type mismatch
```

at this line:

```
Call SendEmail(emailFields)
```

Coming from javascript and PHP background, so not sure what's triggering this error or what I am missing.

Comment: I would think that if `emailAddress` is just a string, just use `String` as type. So `Sub SendEmail(email As String)` and then `queryString = "email = " & email` should suffice.

Comment: Maybe use "as new emailbody" ? The emailFields  should be nothing right now

Comment: @MattCremeens indeed that would work - but I think the question is much more interesting if we treat it as "how do I pass a user-defined type to a procedure"; encapsulating an undetermined and eventually changing number of parameters in a type *is* a good practice.

Comment: I just simplified the example..there will be numerous other fields in the emailBody, but even this simple example throws the error.

Comment: @Pierre user-defined types aren't objects, you don't `New` them up.

Comment: @Mat'sMug emailBody is declared in the module containing SendEmail()

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. I copied your first snippet to a new standard/procedural module `Module1`, and the click handler to the code-behind of a new form `UserForm1`. All I added was `Debug.Print queryString` in the `SendEmail` procedure, and I'm lazy so I put the handler code in `UserForm_Click` and exposed a public method that calls the handler directly; when I call `userform1.testme` from the immediate pane, it outputs `email=myemail@example.com` as expected.

Comment: You might want to remove the parentheses in the call to SendEmail. This forces passing the argument by value, which is not allowed for user defined types.

Comment: @M.Doerner true, but not with an explicit `Call` though (the error would be "compile error: variable required - can't assign to this expression") - OP's code works as-is on my machine :-/

Comment: So I edited the question and likely found the answer. Tracing @Mat'sMug recreation, I found an additional type declaration.

Comment: So.... I'm still not sure what the problem was... that makes your question unclear, and much less useful than it *could* be.

Comment: @Mat'sMug EmailBody() was declared twice. Removing the Private declaration resolved the error. Why that caused a ByRef error as opposed to a duplicate definition error of some sort...is a mystery to me.